# Why does var work but not const within ruby loop?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to toggle each untagged task. 
This works,

```
<% @untagged.each do |task| %> 
    var task_id = <%= task.id %>;
    $(`#${task_id}`).fadeToggle();
<% end %>
```

But, quite curiously this doesn't.

```
<% @untagged.each do |task| %> 
    const task_id = <%= task.id %>;
    $(`#${task_id}`).fadeToggle();
<% end %>
```

From my understanding, every loop creates a new block. The constant declaration will be nested in each of these blocks, thus there wouldn't be any redeclarations. So why is the second example not working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you’re asking why you can’t redeclare/muate a constant?

Comment: Assuming, `@untagged` is an array/collection with more than one member, you're attempting to declare the constant `task_id` multiple times, which will throw a JavaScript error. `var`s can be declared multiple times (the last declaration will be the one that counts), `const`s can only be declared once.

Comment: As @NMPennypacker said, you can't redeclare the JS constant. You're looping in ruby, so the scope of the constant is _not_ within a loop. If the loop was a js function then it may behave differently.

Comment: Got it! Thanks all for your prompt and kind inputs. Have a happy new year!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does your code do?

For every element in `@untagged`, it generates the following lines of code:

```
const task_id = FOO;
$(`#${task_id}`).fadeToggle();
```

with `FOO` replaced by the element's ID. Let's assume, `@untagged` looks like this: `[<#Task @id = 23>, <#Task @id = 24>]`, then the generated code will look like this:

```
const task_id = 23;
$(`#${task_id}`).fadeToggle();
const task_id = 42;
$(`#${task_id}`).fadeToggle();
```

In ECMAScript, `const`ants can only be declared and assigned once, ergo, you get a static error. That's just how constants work in ECMAScript and doesn't really have anything to do with [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) at all.